# Shared Variable between Parent and Child in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, singleton

I have a global configuration `pp` that changes at *runtime* and needs it to be shared across all parent/child objects.

```
class Config:
    pp = 'Init'
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
class Child(Config):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cc = name

par = Config()
print(f"Parent: {par.pp}")
par.pp = "123"
print(f"Parent: {par.pp}")
child = Child('XYZ')
print(f"Child-1: {child.pp} - {child.cc}")
```

This prints:

```
Parent: Init 
Parent: 123 
Child-1: Init - XYZ
```

The third line is expected to be `Child-1: 123 - XYZ`

How can I implement that in a clean way?

UPDATE*
Currently it works with a method like:

```
class Config:
    pp = 'Init'
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def set_pp(self, val):
        type(self).pp = val
```

Comment: You meant to write: `Config.pp = "123"`

Comment: Exactly; pp changes at runtime, this should reflect to all children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the parent of `Child` is not `par` (which is an instance of `Config`, but it is the class `Config`. So you could change the value directly on the class, like that:

```py
class Config:
    pp = 'Init'
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
class Child(Config):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cc = name

print(f"Parent: {Config.pp}")
Config.pp = "123"
print(f"Parent: {Config.pp}")
child = Child('XYZ')
print(f"Child-1: {child.pp} - {child.cc}")
```

Note that if you want to keep the same syntax, you could write

```py
class Config:
    _pp = "Init"

    @property
    def pp(self):
        return self._pp
    
    @pp.setter
    def pp(self, value):
        self.__class__._pp = value

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
class Child(Config):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cc = name

par = Config()
print(f"Parent: {par.pp}")
par.pp = "123"
print(f"Parent: {par.pp}")
child = Child('XYZ')
print(f"Child-1: {child.pp} - {child.cc}")
```

In this version, the `pp` is set from the `parent` object, to the class `Config`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer works great! But there's a kind of code verbosity: `pp` and `_pp`. If I have many properties, it will be very ugly. Can it get cleaner?

Comment: It is already not the best approach to write something like that, since you are in fact not modifying the instance of the parent, but the parent class itself. I think the best way to make your intention clear would be to make your modifications directoy on `Config.pp`.
And to answer your question, you could make it work with a dictionary and the `__getattr__` method to make the code shorter, but I am not sure if it will be cleaner...

Answer (score 1):

One way you could to is to do it via properties that reroute the getter to the parent.
For example via

```
class Config:
    pp = 'Init'
    
class Child(Config):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cc = name

    @property
    def pp(self):
        return Config.pp

    @property.setter
    def pp(self, value):
       Config.pp = value
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked to do this more cleanly in your comment, without adding getter and setter methods, I would suggest to use composition rather than inheritance. Simply pass an instance of `Config` to the child, rather than subclassing it.

```py
class Config:
    pp = 'Init'
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
class Child:
    def __init__(self, name, par):
        self.cc = name
        self.par = par

par = Config()
print(f"Parent: {par.pp}")
par.pp = "123"
print(f"Parent: {par.pp}")
child = Child('XYZ', par)
print(f"Child-1: {child.par.pp} - {child.cc}")
```

Comment: This look indeed cleaner and make more sense to me, however with this version, if you change the value on the parent, it will not be reflected on the child.

Comment: It actually reflects on the child::: par = Config()
print(f"Parent: {par.pp}")
par.pp = "123"
print(f"Parent: {par.pp}")
child = Child('XYZ', par)
par.pp = "456"
print(f"Child-1: {child.par.pp} - {child.cc}")

Comment: If you change it on the parent class it will not change on the child, since that is holding an instance of the parent. In the example the attribute is changed on the instance though and that will reflect (since it's the same instance as the one you're passing to the child).